# Extracting three euler angles from top and bottom two 3D points/one vector of unsymmetrical object

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry, rotation, euler-angles

I know two 3D-points in a line (top and bottom of an unsymmetrical object), and would like to find euler angles(rotation along x, y and z axis).

**Example:** Need reverse engineering of following code of OpenGL, below is the just an example to show the scenario.

```
//Translation
glTranslated(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);

//Rotation
glRotatef(rot.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(rot.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(rot.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

// Draw the object ALONG Y-AXIS
p2 = DrawMyObject(); //p2 is top of my object
```

Now in some situations I got only p1 and p2 and I need to know euler angles (roation along x, y and z axis). How?

**This is what I tried and answer should be (Rx, Ry, Rz): (4, -3, -11),**

```
cv::Point3d p1, p2;
p1.x = 0.0525498;
p1.y = 0.0798909;
p1.z = -1.20806;

p2.x = 0.0586557;
p2.y = 0.111226;
p2.z = -1.20587;

double dx, dy, dz;
double angle;

dx = p2.x - p1.x;
dy = p2.y - p1.y;
dz = p2.z - p1.z;

angle = std::atan2(dy, dz); angle = RAD2DEG(angle);
std::cout<<"\n atan2(dy, dz): "<<int(90 - angle);

angle = std::atan2(dx, dz); angle = RAD2DEG(angle);
std::cout<<"\n atan2(dz, dx): "<<angle;

angle = std::atan2(dy, dx); angle = RAD2DEG(angle);
std::cout<<"\n atan2(dy, dx): "<<int(angle -90);

std::cout<<std::endl;
```

I am not getting exactly correct answer, especially rotation along Y is not correct at all. I think p1 and p2 both lies in y-axis while rotating along y-axis so the problem is. Then what is best possible solution?

Comment: One issue is that a single vector isn't enough information to determine three angles.  There is still an arbitrary rotation around the vector.

Comment: Hi @VaughnCato means I must need 3 points? Any nice reference?

Comment: You don't necessarily need three points, but you need some additional constraint, such as that the total rotation should be minimized, or that one of the three angles is zero.  Having a third point is certainly a possibility though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As stated in the comments you will need either a 3rd point on your object or a constant world-space vector. Be aware that using a constant vector could introduce gimbal problems depending on your specific application and the orientation of the line relative to that vector so a third point might be preferable if you have it.
2. Construct an orthonormalized 3x3 rotation matrix:

   1. Use the [Grahm-Schmit method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to orthonormalize the first two rows where:

      - u1 = p2 - p1
      - u2 = p3 - p1  (or a constant vector)
      - After applying Grahm-Schmit, these vectors will become the first 2 rows of your 3x3 matrix.
   2. The third row of your matrix is just the cross-product of those first two rows.
3. [Decompose the resulting matrix into euler angles.](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846)

Comment: I accepted you answer because that is the exact theory behind. However, I have used Eigen lib's new added feature: Eigen::Vector3f euler_angles = Eigen::Isometry3f(T).rotation().eulerAngles(0,1,2); where T is Eigen::Matrix4f transformation matrix.